# How to make jQuery click event working on angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have some experienced with jQuery. So, I can write basic jQuery code. Recently, I'm learning angular js. I've followed some tutorial and their sample code.

Now, I like to practice some basic thing with angular which I could write easily with jQuery. But, I don't understand how easily I can write those with angular or as a very beginner, If i can't find an way to write those with angular, how can I make the jQuery code working directly inside angular? As, it's my first question about angular here and I'm beginner with angular, it could be some mistake to write the question title or description clearly. Sorry for that if that happened. But, after seeing my fiddles you'll be clear about my confusion.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/47tbnj5m/) where I wrote the jQuery successfully. And [this is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/7s8f2bva/2/) where I have applied `angular.js` and seeking help to make this work for learning purpose. Thanks in advance.

Some sample code of last fiddle:

HTML:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete-item pull-right" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="deleteItem"></span>
```

JS:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function() {
    $(this).parents('.item').remove();
  };
```

Comment: Your code samples should be included directly in your question.

Comment: `$(this)` probably isn't what you think it is. Do not interact with the dom directly within your controller, do so within a directive. That said, you should replace your slidetoggle with a simple flag stored on the scope and ng-show. the remove should simply remove the item from the array, the view will auto-update to reflect it.

Comment: Within a directive, how can I define function would work on single element not every element which we defined by $(this) at jQuery? I mean, what'll be the function then?

Comment: the directive does that by default, use the `elem` param.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angulars binding makes it so you don't have to do things like manipulate the DOM directly (i.e., remove the `div` directly).

In your example, you'd be better off removing the phone from the `$scope.phones` array.

Also, you're doing `ng-click="deleteItem"`, you need to declare it as `deleteItem()`

Your `deleteItem` function might look like this:

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(phone) {
    var index = $scope.phones.indexOf(phone);
    $scope.phones.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And then you'd:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete-item pull-right" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="deleteItem(phone)"></span>
```

For hiding, it would be similar, like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link toggle-details pull-right" style="padding: 0 12px;" ng-click="toggleDes(phone)" ng-switch="phone.hidden || false">
    <span ng-switch-when="true">Show</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="false">Hide</span>
</button>

 $scope.toggleDes = function(phone) {
     phone.hidden = !phone.hidden;
 };
```

And you can change the text with an `ng-switch`

See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yds6r3n8/2/)

Comment: ok, I got how should be deleted something, But, about toggle function, I have a function for changing the text from "Show" to "Hide" or in inverse at the time of toggle. How to do that in angular format?

Answer (score 2):

Removal can be done without an event handler:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete-item pull-right" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="phones.splice($index, 1)"></span>
```

and the slideToggle could be done using a property on the phone and ng-show, ng-hide, or ng-if (again, without an event handler).

```
  <div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones" class="panel panel-default item">
      <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete-item pull-right" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="phones.splice($index, 1)"></span>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link toggle-details pull-right" style="padding: 0 12px;" ng-click="phone.hide = !phone.hide">{{phone.hide ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}}</button>
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{phone.name}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body" ng-hide="phone.hide">
          <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fx5pLfet/4/

Comment: Got it, But without an event handler how can I change my text from "Hide" to "Show" or in inverse at the time of toggle?

Comment: By using a tertiary operator. see update. `{{phone.hide ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}}`

Comment: Note, doing this logic in the controller (see @Tom's answer) is likely better in the long run just in case you need to do more than delete it from tha array, or change a property on a phone. It's also far easier to run unit tests on a controller than it is to run one on a view.

Comment: One more thing please! toggle acts like jQuery show() or hide() method not toggle() method (I mean there is no smooth effect). Is there any easy solution for it in angular way?

Comment: Yes, use a css class and a css transition.

Comment: Is there only CSS way for that?

Comment: Probably not, but it's the best way. Far less complex than the alternative, and probably more performant.

Comment: @user1896653, check out something like [angular ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion), particularly the accordion (?) which does mostly what you're looking for, and you can build in the delete.  There's also `ngAnimate.js` which might help you do what you want, but you're still going to have to write the CSS for the animations.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your help which helps me clearing some confusion. Honestly, I ain't sure whose answer should I accept as I am new. I mean, if I asked any question about which I've idea, I can understand then which solution can be standard or will be easy to me. According to that, I may be accept answer. Since, I am very beginner at angular, I can't tell now which is the standard and will be easy for me to understand/implement. So, please don't mind after thinking some more times if I can't accept your answer(systemically). I wish I could accept both of your answers #Kevin B & #Tom.

Comment: I would say Tom's is more correct, the point of my answer was to show that the same could also be done directly within the template, even if that isn't the *best* way to do it. Tom's answer would be far easier to implement unit testing into and expand upon later.

Comment: You have a great heart! Thanks again